# Can a Linux 'case' statement have an 'or' concept?

Tags: bash, shell, case

Linux can use **case** much like many languages, so:

```
case ${x} in
    one)
        echo "1"
        ;;
    two)
        echo "2"
        ;;
esac
```

Can you do the same with either **$x** or **$y** though? So, imaginatively:

```
case ( ${x} or ${y} ) in
    one)
        echo "1"
        ;;
    two)
        echo "2"
        ;;
esac
```

This meaning that if either **$x** or **$y** contains *one* or *two* then *1* or *2* is printed respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you could loop over the values and the case:

```
for v in "$x" "$y"; do 
    case "$v" in
    one) echo "1"; break ;;
    two) echo "2"; break ;;
    esac
done
```

That would print `1` or `2` for the first one of `$x` and `$y` that match. Of course what to do if both match, is up to you to decide.

Comment: That's an absolutely brilliant answer and I like it - many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know what possible values `$x` and `$y` will have you can build strings such as `"$x$y"` and look for glob patterns, eg:

```
case $x$y in
    *one*) echo "1" ;;
    *two*) echo "2" ;;
esac
```

Comment: This matches e.g. if `$x` is `on` and `$y` is `eeek`.

Comment: That's why I said you need to reflect on what possible values x and y might have. For example, you might need to use `case "+$x+$y+"` and match for `*+one+*`, but that will obviously match `x=+one+` and not just `x=one`, and so on. The answer applies if the script has previously set x and y to a limited set of known values.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a character that cannot appear in any of the variables' value, then you can use this character as a separator. For example, suppose that you've determined that neither the value of x, nor the value of y, can contain a colon

```
case ":${x}:${y}:" in
    *:one:*)
        echo "1"
        ;;
    *:two:*)
        echo "2"
        ;;
esac
```

This scales easily to a variable number of strings. But do keep in mind that you have to find a character (here `:`) or even a sequence of characters that cannot possibly occur in the strings that you're testing.